# Getting data from table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table contains following fields.

1. Name
2. audit_id
3. review_status
4. user_id
5. user_email  I want the pull record as below.

   - table should contain 300 random records of each user_email.

For instance: 
Table has 12000 rows. 8 Unique user_email. So while pulling the record, I will need to get 300 random (not distinct) records for each user_email.Totally I should get 2400 records. I tried the below.

```
select SR.name,
       MCR.cr_id,
       MCR.review_status,
       MCR.last_update_time,
       MCR.description,
       CNT.id as user_id,
       CNT.email as user_email
from   manual_cr_review as MCR,
       selling_rule as SR,
       contact as CNT
join selling_rule SR
join manual_creative_review MCR
join contact CNT on  SR.id=MCR.rule_id
                and  CNT.id=MCR.contact_id
MCR.last_update_time >='2017-07-10 00:00:00' 
and MCR.last_update_time <'2017-07-14 23:59:59' 
and CNT.id in (123,234)
order by 
rand () limit 600;
```

From this I am getting random record for 2 users but its not exactly 300 & 300. I need this to be fixed.

Any modifications. !!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following query:

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM (
  SELECT distinct user_email
  FROM table
  LIMIT 2
) a,
(SELECT *
 FROM table
 WHERE user_email = a.user_email
 LIMIT 300) b;
```